# How to get CSS Modules to work in Vue class binding?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Google already can't help me.

I have template in Vue like this:

```
<template>
    <button
        :class="{ 'button-selected': isSelected }">
    </button>
</template>
```

Everything works great until I try to use CSS Modules:

```
<template>
    <button
        :class="{ styles['button-selected']: isSelected }">
    </button>
</template>

...

import styles from "./Button.scss"

...

data () {
    return {
        styles
    }
}
```

Sure. I can't use it, since

```
let obj = { style['button-selected']: this.isSelected }
```

are also invalid expression.

I found temporary solution:

```
<template>
    <button
        :class="classes">
    </button>
</template>
...
computed: {
    classes () {
        let obj = {}
        obj[this.styles['button-selected']] = this.isSelected
        return obj
    }
}
```

But since I use this pattern I need to create a computed prop for each element.
I'm trying to find another way to do it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use es6 [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) names:

```html
<button :class="{ [styles['button-selected']]: isSelected }">
```

The outer brackets around `styles['button-selected']` evaluate that expression as a property name.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      isSelected: true,
      styles: {
        'button-selected': 'redclass'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.redclass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button :class="{ [styles['button-selected']]: isSelected }">
  asdf
  </button>
</div>
```

You could also use a ternary:

```
<button :class="isSelected ? styles['button-selected'] : ''">
```

Comment: It was so easy! Thank you!